# How to fetch single record for duplicate record

Tags: php

I am facing an problem.I have a folder with images.Some images has same name and some are unique.I have to fetch all the duplicate images from that folder and move it to another folder and keep unique images in same folder.How can i do that.

Comment: could you provide us with your table structure?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  It is not clear what the "duplicate records" are.

Comment: "duplicate record" are i have same zoho_id with multiple times with different images.so i have to fetch zoho_id which exist only one time and i have to move that zoho_id with its images to a folder and duplicate zoho_id with its images to another folder.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of the code you have tried? It might help to get this question a little clearer. Also, this has many parts: How to get items from the database, How to loop through the results, how to check for duplicates, how to move duplicates and how to update database. Can you do any of these steps? If you can, it would us greatly in providing answers if you provided us the code.